# Como criar um programa que entra na web e pega os dados da bolsa de valores

Tags: python-3.x

Bom a minha ideia é criar um programa que pegue os dados das cotações de criptomoedas para eu ficar monitorando, mas eu não sei como pegar esses dados ao vivo e fazer o programa ficar atualizando os dados.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar as sugestões de:

[API para cotação de bolsa de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64278/api-para-cota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-bolsa-de-valores)

São **todas** via HTTP e pagas, a unica marcada como gratuita é para o programa Excel e não creio que vai servir pra isto, o exemplo que parece mais interessante é o Bolsafinanceira, segue o link de como usar:

- http://www.bolsafinanceira.com/api-doc.pdf

Tabelas de preços:

- http://www.bolsafinanceira.com/site/api#quote-tab-3

### Usando com Python 3

No Python 3 você pode usar o `urllib.request` com `json`

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "http://api.bolsafinanceira.com:8080/composition/?token=<seu-token>&codelist=ibovespa,ibrx50"

with urllib.request.urlopen(urlData) as f:
   data = f.read()
   encoding = f.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
   json.loads(data.decode(encoding))
```

Ou usar o `import requests`

> Para instalar use o comando:
>
> ```
>  pip install requests
> ```
>
> Ou pipenv (depende do seu ambiente)
>
> ```
>  pipenv install requests
> ```

Deve ficar assim:

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.bolsafinanceira.com:8080/composition/?token=<seu-token>&codelist=ibovespa,ibrx50';

r = requests.get(url, print=pretty')

# Exibe a resposta
print(r.json())
```

Comment: [AlphaVantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/) também oferece uma API (gratuita com limitações). Contém a maior parte dos símbolos negociados na Bovespa.